# Complications No Longer Updating in watchOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

My perfectly working complications in watchOS 6/5/4 don't work in watchOS 7. This is for an independent watchOS app.

It seems that the method *getCurrentTimelineEntry* doesn't get called although I call *reloadTimeline* for all complications. If running on the sim *getCurrentTimelineEntry* does get called from time to time but still the complications don't update.

So what has changed or is this a known bug in watchOS 7?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that my *CLKComplicationDataSource* derived class (*ComplicationController*) was never called on the device by the API although it was called seldomly on the simulator!

So there are certainly bugs in the API that require the project to be configured/recompiled for watchOS 7 in order to work.

My configuration required the following new changes:

1. Set complication images in WatchKit Extension’s *Assets.xcassets* for all complications. This was optional in watchOS 6 or older.
2. Implement the new *getComplicationDescriptors* and programmatically declare all supported complications. The old way of declaring the supported complications in WatchKit Extension’s *Info.plist* is no longer supported on watchOS 7 even for apps compiled with watchOS 6